# Spurious infinite limit of integration message in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, warning-messages, special-functions

**Bug introduced in 7.0 and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

`NIntegrate` returns an error complaining that `ComplexInfinity` is an invalid limit of integration when passed exact input but not when passed approximate input.

```
eps = 1*^-8;
s1 = InverseJacobiCN[eps, 7/10];
s2 = InverseJacobiCN[-eps, 7/10];

NIntegrate[
 Log[Abs[s - EllipticK[7/10]]], {s, s1, EllipticK[7/10], s2}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

> NIntegrate::nlim: s = ComplexInfinity is not a valid limit of integration. >>

The limits are not infinite:

```
N[{s1, EllipticK[7/10], s2}, 20]
(*
{2.0753631170350505603,
 2.0753631352924691439,
 2.0753631535498877274}
*)
```

I get no error if I approximate the input to a precision of at least the `WorkingPrecision`.  (I get an expected `NIntegrate::precw` precision warning if the precision is set less than `WorkingPrecision`, but the result is still computed.)

```
NIntegrate @@ 
 N[{Log[Abs[s - EllipticK[7/10]]], {s, s1, EllipticK[7/10], s2}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 20}, 20]
(*  -6.8716155958584042728*10^-7  *)
```

I suppose this is probably a bug.  Anyone have another explanation?

Comment: Note that `Integrate` can evaluate the integral and after converting to numerical value gives `-6.8716155958619248034*10^-7`

Comment: `NIntegrate` is effectively doing `Block[{$MinPrecision = $MaxPrecision = 20}, N[EllipticK[7/10], 20]]` which doesn't go so well.

Comment: Thanks @ilian, that sounds like the answer.  It also sounds like a bug I should report, yes?  Do you know how far back this behavior goes?

Comment: Just for completeness: what happens if you replace `EllipticK[7/10]` with `π/(2 ArithmeticGeometricMean[1, Sqrt[3/10]])`?

Comment: @J.M. It works with no problem; the problem seems to be evaluating `EllipticK[7/10]` with the constraints on precision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for this error is that `NIntegrate` uses fixed precision when computing the integration ranges, while `EllipticK` needs to raise the precision internally to obtain a good result.

```
N[EllipticK[7/10], 20]

(* 2.0753631352924691439 *)

Block[{$MinPrecision = $MaxPrecision = 20}, N[EllipticK[7/10], 20]]

(* Divide::infy: Infinite expression 1.0000000000000000000/0 encountered. >> *)
(* ComplexInfinity *)
```

I have submitted a bug report for this issue, thank you for bringing it up. One possible workaround, as mentioned in the question, is to numericize `EllipticK[7/10]` in advance (only needed in the range, the numerical evaluation of the integrand is fine).

As suggested by [Guess who it is. ♦](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) in the comments, we can also obtain a result by expressing `EllipticK` in terms of `ArithmeticGeometricMean`:

```
eps = 1*^-8;
s1 = InverseJacobiCN[eps, 7/10];
s2 = InverseJacobiCN[-eps, 7/10];
elk = Pi/(2 ArithmeticGeometricMean[1, Sqrt[3/10]]);
NIntegrate[Log[Abs[s - EllipticK[7/10]]], {s, s1, elk, s2}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 20]

(* -6.8716155958619248037*10^-7 *)
```

Comment: How very odd. I had assumed `EllipticK[]` was using AGM under the hood, so I was expecting that the same error should pop up. Very curious indeed…